# Rational and irrational fractions over finite fileds

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields

I've been told that over the field $\mathbb{F}_7$ the square root of $2$ is actually $3$.

How come? Why does it happen?

Comment: Do you understand how $\Bbb F_7$ is constructed?

Comment: Have you tried calculating $3\times 3$ in ${\bf F}_7$ and seeing what you get? Also note that $-3=4$ is another square root of $2$, and there is no natural way to distinguish between these two (unlike in the rationals, when positive/negative things can be distinguished).

Comment: @itamar What is $3^2$ in $\Bbb F_7$?

Comment: @itamar If you know all this then I should ask: do you know what it means for something to be a square root of another thing?

Comment: @anon: not true. $4$ is a square in $\mathbb{F}_7$, while $3$ is not.

Comment: @itamar Given $x$, $y$ is said to be a square root of $x$ if $y^2=x$.

Comment: Note, your question subject indicates some configure. What is an "irrational fraction?"  In any event, in $\mathbb F_7$, there really is no sense of things being "irrational."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: not true. $\sqrt{3}$ can be considered (the equivalent of) irrational in $\mathbb{F}_7$, in the same sense as in $\mathbb{Q}$ - it's a root of a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_7$ that isn't itself in $\mathbb{F}_7$.

Comment: About 5 hours ago (presumably mid-morning in Israel), the OP asked this question as a follow-up to [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/365097/15941) of mine on [his earlier question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/364896/15941). Presumably he could not wait for my response, which I posted an hour ago (early morning in the US), and posted this new question right away. I vote to close this question as a duplicate of the previous one.

Comment: No, @GlenO, $\sqrt{3}$ is not an element of $\mathbb F_7$. Saying $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational  in $\mathbb F_7$ is like saying $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational in $\mathbb Q$ - it is a meaningless statement, because it isn't in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: it was probably poor wording - I meant "irrational with respect to $\mathbb{F}_7$", rather than "irrational in $\mathbb{F}_7$".

Comment: Which is still an inappropriate term. A number is "rational" if it is in $\mathbb Q$. An irrational number is a number in $\mathbb R$ which is not in $\mathbb Q$.  You can argue by analogy, but all you are really saying is that $x^2-3$ is prime over $\mathbb F_7$ - there is no way to even single out a $\sqrt{3}$ that you are talking about.

Comment: @Thomas The terms "rational" and "irrational" *are* occasionally used in a generalized way like that suggested by Glen, i.e to denote elements in (or not in) the fraction field of a fixed (ambient) domain. But I do agree that "irrational *in* F" was incorrect. Instead of "*in*", one should say *over*.

Comment: @GlenO Read my comment. I never said $3$ was a square. I said both $3$ and $4$ are elements which square to $2$ in ${\bf F}_7$.

Comment: @anon: You can distinguish $3$ and $4$ quite easily -- $3$ is $1+1+1$ while $4$ is $1+1+1+1$ -- it takes less $1$'s to get a $3$ than $4$. It's a rather natural ordering.

Comment: @tomasz: If "natural" is to mean "first thing that comes to mind," then I agree.

Comment: @tomasz: that method of distinguishing the two is not particularly "natural" in modular arithmetic. You could just as easily say that 4 is 2+2 and 3 is 2+2+2+2+2. But 3 is not a square mod 7, whereas 4 is a square mod 7. That makes 4 the natural "positive" square root of 2, and 3 the "negative" square root of 2.

Comment: @anon: I never said that you said 3 was a square. I said that one can distinguish between the two square roots of 2 by looking at which one is a square in $\mathbb{F}_7$. The fact that 3 isn't a square, but 4 is, allows us to distinguish between the two in the same way that we distinguish between 2 and -2 when finding the square root of 4.

Comment: @GlenO: But $1$ is the most natural definable element in a ring (with unity; except perhaps for $0$), and in one of the form ${\bf Z}/n{\bf Z}$ any element is a sum of $1$s, which is not the case for $2$

Comment: @tomasz: Ah, but $-1$ is equally definable, and a ring of the form $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, any element is also a sum of $-1$s.

Answer (score 2):

First recall that $x$ is a square-root of an element $y$, if we have $x^2 = y$.

$\mathbb{F}_7$ is the set $\{0\pmod7,1\pmod7,2\pmod7,3\pmod7,4\pmod7,5\pmod7,6\pmod7\}$ with the operations $+$ and $\times$. Note that in this set
$$(3 \pmod 7)^2 \equiv 3^2 \pmod7 \equiv 9 \pmod 7 \equiv 2 \pmod7$$
Hence, we get that $3 \pmod7$ is a square-root of $2 \pmod7$. Also, note that $$(4 \pmod7)^2 \equiv 4^2 \pmod 7 \equiv 16 \pmod 7 \equiv 2 \pmod7$$
Hence, the two square-roots of $2 \pmod7$ are $3 \pmod7$ and $4 \pmod7$.

Comment: Correction: **A** square root of 2 is 3. It isn't the only square root.

Comment: @GlenO Reworded. Thanks.

Comment: As an additional note, $4\equiv -3 \pmod 7$.